# Angular Authgaurd not redirecting or forcing application to home page after login

Tags: angular, typescript, api, authentication, auth-guard

Routing module

```
{
    path:'login',
  component:LoginComponent
    },
  {
  path: '',
  component: DefaultComponent,
 canActivate:[AuthGuard],
  children: [{
    path: '',
    component: DashboardComponent
  },
```

Login component.ts

```
let hey=data["API Key"]
    let id=data["id"]
    console.log(id);
    console.log(hey);

    localStorage.setItem("key",hey),
  
    
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
    // window.location.reload(true)
```

Authgaurd.ts

```
canActivate():boolean{
  if (this._authsevice.loggedIN()){
    return true
  }
  else{
    this._router.navigate(['/login'])
    return false
  }
}
```

Authservice.ts

```
export class AuthService{

     loggedIN(){
         return !!localStorage.getItem('key')
     }
}
```

as soon as  authenticated ,it creates a key and stores it
but i cant understand why the page is still being in login page without redirecting or navigating and forcing authservice to search for key
when i forcefully reload the page
i still get the login page and with the second time authentication I'm  able to access all the other pages

i dont understand why
and how to force angular application to view once the key is being stored

Comment: why you set an authguard for your login screen? Use authGuard on routes which should reachable AFTER an successful authentication.

Answer (score 0):

you can return an URL tree, you should do:

```js
canActivate(): boolean | UrlTree {
  if (this._authsevice.loggedIN()){
    return true
  }
  return this._router.navigate(['/login'])
}
```

to answer your question:

use an `Observable` for your login state with a `BehaviourSubject`, you use `Observable<boolean | UrlTre>` as return value in `canActivate`.